# Remove objects with duplicated values from Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I want to remove objects with the same field value from a queryset. I've seen some related answers here, but none of them use the annotate and Min feature and I don't know if that approach is even possible.

Imagine I have a 'Book' model with a 'Library' model FK. A Library could have multiple Books with the same title.

How can I obtain a list of Books from that Library with different titles and lower price?

I've tried different approaches with no success:

models.py

```py
class Library(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Library name'), max_length=255)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(_('Author'), max_length=255)
    editorial = models.CharField(_('Editorial'), max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField(_('Price'), default=0)
    library = models.ForeignKey(Library, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='libraries',
                                related_query_name='libraries')
```

Queryset

```py
Book.objects.annotate(count_id=Count('title'), min_price=Min('price')).filter(library__id=21, price=F('min_price')).values_list('title')
```

Example:

Having this objects
| ID | Title | Price |
|:---- |:------:| :-----|
| 1 | Trainspotting    | 3 |
| 2 | The Catcher in the rye    | 2 |
| 3 | Trainspotting    | 1 |
| 4 | Lord of the Rings    | 5 |
| 5 | Trainspotting    | 5 |

I want to obtain the following queryset:

| ID | Title | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | The Catcher in the rye | 2 |
| 3 | Trainspotting | 1 |
| 4 | Lord of the Rings | 5 |

EDIT:

Using the `distinct=True` in Count gives me the following results:

In this case my Library contains two Trainspotting books with the same price and two titles of 'The Catcher in the Rye' with prices 2 and 4.

Here I'm printing the annotated fields within the name to see what's could be wrong: `Book.objects.annotate(count_id=Count('title', distinct=True), min_price=Min('price')).filter(library__id=21, price=F('min_price')).values_list('name', 'min_price', 'count_id')`

The QS I obtain is the following:

```
<QuerySet [('Trainspotting', 1.0, 1), ('Trainspotting', 1.0, 1), ('The Catcher in the Rye', 2.0, 1), ('The Catcher in the Rye', 4.0, 1)]>
```

Thanks you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Book.objects.values('title').annotate(count=Count('title'), price=Min('price'))
```

This will return you the count of titles per title, and also the minimum price per title.

You need to pay attention to the order of `annotate` and `values`. You can have a read here for a detailed explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

Comment: I'm afraid it wont work in my case, because I'm using an SQLite db. But I really appreciate your answer and I'm sure it will help someone. Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, why won't it work on SQLite?

Comment: I've just tried your answer and I works like charm. Thank you very much! I had the belief that annotations only works with PostgreSQL and recently with MySQL db backends. So sorry for that my friend!